# Input in Box2D Bodies

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I have created rigid bodies placed upon each other in a structural way. I want to know if a body is touched by the user or not for all bodies even in rotation , free falling etc.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to figure out if a screen touch is over a body or not?

Comment: yes I am trying to figure out a screen touch is over a body or not

Comment: I could only do it for vertical position using isTouched() Method in the input processor class by applying limits to the screenX, screenY

Comment: the `touchDown()` method of the `InputProcessor` gives you screenX and screenY. You have to convert them to worldcoordinates by using your pixel to meter conversion, or the `camera.unproject` method. Then chekc, if one of your bodies is on that coordinate.

Comment: @Springrbua how to check if body is on the coordinate I want to if it is touched interior or on the fixture or not

Comment: I don't know much about Box2D. But you should have the position of the body/fixture and its size/shape. So you can check if this point (touchpoint) is inside this body/fixture or not. Maybe box2d has a method for that, if not you have to look for a method, cuase it depends on the shape and how accurate you want to be with that touch

Comment: @Springbua Its rectangular shape I know its centre at any given time of render and length and height

Comment: Look at the source code for the Box2D testbed, it does this.

Comment: Have a look at one of my old gists: https://gist.github.com/nooone/8363982